# how can i get the Quantity by considering two conditions in table customer_stock

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, database

I am stuck with a problem in php, mysql and json
I am not able to retrieve data from the database by selecting two conditions
I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TKnh.png) as well
I want to retrieve the quantity from table `customer_stock` by considering two conditions: customer and name

```
$line = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM stock_details  WHERE stock_name ='" . $_POST['stock_name1'] . "'");
$cost = $line->company_price;
$sell = $line->selling_price;
$stock_id = $line->stock_id;
$line = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM customer_stock WHERE name='" . $_POST['stock_name1'] . "'");

$stock = $line->quantity;

if ($line != NULL) {

    $arr = array("cost" => "$cost", "sell" => "$sell", "stock" => "$stock", "guid" => $stock_id);
    echo json_encode($arr);

} else {
    $arr1 = array("no" => "no");
    echo json_encode($arr1);
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that you're overwritting the `$line` variable? I can't see the screenshot also...

Anyways, I think that you're trying to do a `JOIN`, so you need a field to match each row with its associate in the other table.

Comment: I can see the code, but I can't see the image, sorry :(

Comment: please see now i have attached screen shot

Comment: Anyway I will need to see the database schema to try to guess what SQL query you need to do. Specially I need to see the relationships between the tables.